# xampp and tomcat and jsp oh my.. how do i tell if its working

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, xampp

Ok recently installed a wamp xammp to be specific.. I have a requirment to use jsp for some server side communications instead of other stuff like php. My main issue is not knowing jsp enough or java for that matter to know whether or not what I'm trying to do is working or if its not and if its not is it cause of the code I'm tempting to try which is a copy and paste solution via Google for "jsp hello world". Xampp reports tomcat as active and running but I copy and paste the jsp code I find to see if it works and when I go to it in my browser I just see the source as if I were looking at it in notepad, so anyone got some advice? This is a stock install if the latest xammp.. the server runs fine other wise php and mysql included.

Comment: Hint, put your mouse above the `jsp` tag below your question until a popbox shows and then click the *info* link. That's the tag wiki page. At the bottom you can find links to several decent JSP tutorials.

Comment: I didn't know that about the site, I thought those tabs took me to more questions by other people in the same category, I will go check those out now, thank you.

Comment: No, do not click the tag directly, just wait until a black box pops up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the file has the `.jsp` extension and that it's been placed in a subfolder of `/xampp/tomcat/webapps` (and thus not there where you usually drop PHP files).

#### See also:

- [Youtube video tutorial - Integrating Tomcat with Apache using XAMPP](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUV_jPdq7fc)

Comment: dropping it in this sub folder, do I still access it the same way I would otherwise. Meaning if I go into my browser http://localhost/monkeys/test.php I get my php file like you say normally. But would I access the JSP the same way through the same url? Example changing test.php to test.jsp

Comment: I have never used Xampp for JSP, so I can't go in details. But the symptoms indicate that your JSP doesn't have the proper extension or that it is simply not served by Tomcat at all. Read the Xampp documentation or the abovelinked video tutorial. You should understand that JSP is to be served by Apache Tomcat and that PHP is to be served by Apache HTTPD. That are completely different webservers.

Comment: Cool, yea.. I dislike being new to anything. This JSP stuff has me baffled to say the least at the moment. I do appreciate the help though.

Comment: Good luck. Suggestion: you should put PHP totally out of your head for a while. Developing with JSP while thinking the PHP way will result in a complete disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Install NetBeans IDE and follow this tutorial: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html (before running application in this tutorial you must stop your XAMPP Tomcat).

Or if you want to use your XAMPP Tomcat, integrate it with NetBeans, create a web project using that tutorial, create a WAR file (by clicking on button Clean and Build) - this will create a WAR file in your project directory in directory "dist" and then copy this WAR file to your XAMPP Tomcat into directory webapps.

Start small, use NetBeans IDE, read some tutorials and experiment. Later you can switch to Eclipse IDE (IMHO buch better IDE, but requires much more customization than NetBeans).

Dont use Notepad.